# What are "collector" and "gather" found in /lib/bootchart/?

Tags: permissions

I noticed a process, "collector" was eating up 7% or so of my processor time when I ran top. There were no man pages on it, and I found it with another executable, "gather" in `/lib/bootchart/`.

I killed it with no noticeable effect. I disabled execute permissions on both collector and gather. It makes me uneasy to find software without finding documentation for it, which has no `-h` or `--help` option. It has no`-nodaemon` option.

My operating system is Ubuntu vers. 15.10

My question: does anyone know what those two executables are?

```
dd@d-T900:/lib/bootchart$ ./collector
Usage: ./collector [-r] HZ [DIR]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that these two files are part of the bootchart and/or the pybootchartgui package. **Looking at xenial contents for bootchart with this url:**

```
- url: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/bootchart/filelist
```

**shows the following files:**

```
- /etc/init.d/bootchart
- /etc/init/bootchart.conf
- /lib/bootchart/collector
- /lib/bootchart/gather
- /usr/share/doc/bootchart/changelog.Debian.gz
- /usr/share/doc/bootchart/copyright
- /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/bootchart
- /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/bootchart
```

I'm not sure why it is still running well after the boot has completed - I'll leave answering that to someone else. I believe they are 'harmless' to nerf, though it might be better to uninstall the bootchart / pybootchartgui package/s instead.

I found this question looking for an answer to same - to answer my own question I pulled up synaptic and searched for collector, gather, and bootchart (coming from the directory the files are found in).

bootchart is a nifty little utility to help grok the sequence and timing of boot events. I do not know of any reason to keep running the package if you aren't interested in boot event sequencing/timing.

-wc

Comment: Thank you, wc! I love reading a clear answer to a simple question!  A rare gem among the many dismissive comments one finds in place of answers so often in these forums! Bravo!